# Nodejs Express redirect to shareable unique url with client JS working

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Express in Node and I want to do these:

If user comes to the page (hi) or a new url that never existed (hi/wxyz4321)

- Gets redirected to the same page, but with a unique url, that can be shared to others (hi/abcd1234)
- "abcd1234" gets appended to an array called URLS

Here are the codes:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const nanoid = require('nanoid');
const fs = require('file-system');
var URLS = [];
var ID = nanoid();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"))
app.use("/styles",  express.static(__dirname + '/public/css'));
app.use("/scripts", express.static(__dirname + '/public/js'));
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/index.html'));
});

app.get("/*", function(req, res){
    var origin= req.url.slice(-21);
    //-21 because that is the length of nanoid generated
    if(URLS.includes(origin)===false){
        URLS.push(ID);
        fs.copyFileSync('public/index.html', "public/"+randomID+".html");
        //Creates a new html file with the name of ID
        //But res.redirect(__dirname + "/public/randomID"); does not work
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `res.redirect`?

Comment: Before I can redirect, I need to create a new URL first right?

Comment: There is a redirect loop in your description. If someone comes in with `hi/abcd1234` you must not redirect them to `hi/abcd1234`, because then they would be coming in with `hi/abcd1234` again.

Comment: Wait, you mean the third condition is not necessary right? Yeah, thanks for reminding me that!

Comment: Correct. Your logic should be *"if `id` is unknown ("undefined" is just a special case of unknown, no need to make a difference), create new ID and redirect to that ID."* There is no "else".

Comment: Alright, so I have edited the post accordingly.  Maybe I can npm install fs, then make a new html file with ID as its file name if Id is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have probably found my answer. My redirecting works, but Chrome is blocking me from loading local resource, so I will need to deploy this into a server to be 100% sure. It did redirect me to Google and other existing sites though.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const nanoid = require('nanoid');
const fs = require('file-system');
var URLS = [];
var ID = nanoid();
//app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"))
//I removed this line, because redirect will not work if user comes to index.html
app.use("/styles",  express.static(__dirname + '/public/css'));
app.use("/scripts", express.static(__dirname + '/public/js'));
//Retaining these two lines, because these lines where the css and js are kept

app.get("/*", function(req, res){
    var origin= req.url.slice(-21);
    //-21 because that is the length of nanoid generated
    if(URLS.includes(origin)===false){
        URLS.push(ID);
        fs.copyFileSync('public/index.html', "public/"+randomID+".html");
        //Creates a new html file with the name of ID
        var destination = '<script>window.location.href=' + '"' + __dirname + "/public/"+ randomID + '";</script>';
        //var destination = '<script>window.location.href=' + '"' +"https://www.google.com.my/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi&ogbl"+ '";</script>';
        //Since this line worked, it will probably work if I test this on a real server
        res.send(destination);
        //Redirects to the newly created html file
    }
});
```